# jQuery Mousewheel - deltaFactor is always 100

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use [jQuery Mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) plugin and - for tests - I put the exact same code as the author of the plugin did:

```
$('body').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
    console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor);
});
```

Problem is - I'm always getting `100` for `deltaFactor`, and citing the author, it shouldn't behave like that:

> In some use-cases we prefer to have the normalized delta but in others
> we want to know how far the browser should scroll based on the users
> input. This can be done by multiplying the deltaFactor by the deltaX
> or deltaY event property to find the scroll distance the browser
> reported.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's fine. It simply means you have mouse wheel acceleration turned off. Simply use `event.deltaX * event.deltaFactor` and it will work everywhere.

Comment: `event.deltaX` returns `-1` and `event.deltaFactor` returns `100` every time.

Comment: Well, try to go to http://volkhin.com/RoadTrafficSimulator and zoom in/out using mouse wheel. I'm using this jquery-mousewheel plugin in this project so we can understand if something wrong with your code or browser/system.

Comment: Problem is obviously with my computer, since on my friends Sony notebook all works well. Nevertheless, I solved my problem by adding `num++` and placing it in `on('mousewheel')...` code ;-)